# Are accessibility programs/browsers able to read an angular/ng-repeat generated list that gets the data from a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, wcag2.0

I have an angular powered listing with filtering capabilities on a site. I am wondering if the accessibility programs/browsers know how to read and filter the data.

I am guessing that 
- by read I mean that the program executes the js and interprets it correctly
- by filter I mean the used buttons that to do the filtering(eg filter by type) or the search text box have an effect on the list that will be read/presented to the user

Thank you